# Binding an NSTableView to an NSMutableArray

Tags: cocoa, nsarray, cocoa-bindings

I'm learning Cocoa, and I've got a problem: I would like to bind the content of an NSMutableArray to an NSTableView, with bindings. I read many documentations about them, but I can't manage to make them work (nothing is displayed in my table).

Here are the facts:

I created a simple model, called `MTMTask` which contains 2 properties, `priority` and `text`:

MTMTask.h

```
@interface MTMTask : NSObject {
 NSString *priority;
 NSString *text;
}

@property(copy) NSString* priority;
@property(copy) NSString* text;

- (id) initWithPriority :(NSString*)newPriority andText:(NSString*)newText;

@end
```

MTMTask.m

```
#import "MTMTask.h"

@implementation MTMTask

@synthesize text, priority;

- (id) initWithPriority:(NSString *)newPriority andText:(NSString *)newText {
 if (self = [super init]) {
  priority = newPriority;
  text = newText;
  return self;
 }
 return nil;
}

@end
```

Then I've created the MTMTaskController :

MTMTaskController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "MTMTask.h"

@interface MTMTaskController : NSObject {
 NSMutableArray *_tasksList;
}

- (NSMutableArray *) tasksList; 

@end
```

MTMTaskController.m

```
#import "MTMTaskController.h"

@implementation MTMTaskController

- (void) awakeFromNib
{ 
 MTMTask *task1 = [[MTMTask alloc] initWithPriority:@"high" andText:@"Feed the hungry cat"];
 MTMTask *task2 = [[MTMTask alloc] initWithPriority:@"low" andText:@"Visit my family"];

 _tasksList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:task1, task2, nil];
}

- (NSMutableArray*) tasksList
{
 return _tasksList;
}

@end
```

And finally I edited the MainMenu.xib: I added a `NSObject` and set its class to `MTMTaskController`. Then I added an NSArrayController, called `TasksListController`, with its content outlet bound to `MTMTaskController.tasksList`. I also set its mode to `Class` and class name `MTMTask`. I bound the `value` outlet of two columns of an `NSTableView` to `TasksListController` text and priority.

But when I run the program, well, it's not really a success: nothing shows up in the table.

Have you got an idea concerning my problem? I think I'm missing something but I can't figure what.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you set breakpoints to make sure that the controller and the objects are actually being created? You may have forgotten to add the controller as an object in the xib file, in which case `awakeFromNib` will not get called.

Comment: Just tried: I put an NSLog() call in `awakeFromNib`, and it is displayed in the console. Looks like the problem isn't there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are allocating objects for the controller in awake from nib, you create the objects, add them to an array and then set that array as the task list.

The thing about bindings is that you need to be aware of KVO (Key value observing) which is the mechanism by which bound objects know that the things they have bound to have changed.

In the awake from nib method you have just set the array directly which doesn't invoke KVO.

I have created an example Xcode project (Xcode 3.1) which you can [download from here](http://bitbucket.org/abizern/tasker/get/147f129f6479.zip). This creates a property for the task list and within the awakeFromNib method I am assigning the array using property syntax, which takes care of KVO for you:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    Task *task1 = [[Task alloc] initWithPriority:@"high" andText:@"Feed the cat"];
    Task *task2 = [[Task alloc] initWithPriority:@"low" andText:@"Visit my familiy"];

    self.taskArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:task1, task2, nil];
```

}

Alternatively, you could sandwich the assignment in `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` messages, but I'll leave that as an excercise for you.

Comment: It works very well! Thank you very much! I think have understood your explaination. I need to use @property more often.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I came across the exact same problem today.

Comment: Your explanation helped me, too. Thank you for saving me a huge headache!